# save in SharedPreferences Callback

Tags: android, sharedpreferences, listener, android-sharedpreferences

After button click I need to wait till some information will be stored in `SharedPreferences` and then move on into the next activity. I try to use `SharedPreferences.OnSharedPreferenceChangeListener()` but it isn't work properly.

**MapActivity**

```
button.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View view) {
                if (currentPosition != null ) {
                    SharedPreferences preferences = PreferenceHelper.getPreferences(MapActivity.this);
                    SharedPreferences.OnSharedPreferenceChangeListener preferenceChangeListener = new SharedPreferences.OnSharedPreferenceChangeListener() {
                        @Override
                        public void onSharedPreferenceChanged(SharedPreferences sharedPreferences, String key) {
                           Log.i(TAG,"key "+key);
                            Intent i = new Intent(MapActivity.this, MainActivity.class);
                            i.putExtra("coordinates", currentPosition);
                            i.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP | Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_SINGLE_TOP);
                            startActivity(i);
                        }
                    };
                   preferences.registerOnSharedPreferenceChangeListener(preferenceChangeListener);
                    PreferenceHelper.saveLocation(MapActivity.this,currentPosition);
                }
            }
        });
```

**PreferencesHelper**

```
 public class PreferenceHelper {
                public static SharedPreferences appPreference;

                 public static SharedPreferences getPreferences(Context context){

                return  context.getSharedPreferences(PREFERENCES_NAME,Context.MODE_PRIVATE);
            }

                public static void saveLocation(Context context,LatLng location){
                    appPreference=context.getSharedPreferences(PREFERENCES_NAME,Context.MODE_PRIVATE);
                SharedPreferences.Editor editor = appPreference.edit();
                editor.putFloat(CURRENT_LOCATION_X, (float) location.latitude).apply();
                editor.putFloat(CURRENT_LOCATION_Y, (float) location.longitude).apply();
                editor.commit();
            }

            }
```

Comment: r u tried by mentioning the PreferenceHelper.saveLocatio at top of the SharedPreferences.OnSharedPreferenceChangeListener ?

Comment: yes i try that way

Answer (score 1):

Commiting changes is something that happens in the main thread...You don't need a OnSharedPreferenceChangeListener. the change listener is useful when you want to be notified about changes in your shared preferences that were commited from other components of your application...not the one that commited the changes. Just do:

```
prefs.edit().putWhatever().commit();
startActivity(new Intent(....));
```

Comment: I ve been tested the code without OnSharedPreferenceChangeListener and it work fine in android 6.0 but in older ones (4.2) have a problem with it (it takes data from previous savings, like it need more time untill save it).

Comment: That could happend because the activity you re starting is "heavy". Saving two float values can't have that kind of concequence. Unless your preferences file has grown so big that it needs a lot of time to save. In which case you 're doing something wrong and you should save your data in a different way...e.g. database